# onSnapshot not triggering in vercel for ReactJS project for Web Version 9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vercel

I am learning ReactJS and I am a beginner.

I am trying to get the real-time data change from firebase firestore.

```
useEffect(() => {
    getValues();
  });
```

```
const q = query(collection(db, "users"));
const getValues = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
    const updateUser = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      updateUser.push(doc.data());
    });
    setUsers([...updateUser]);
  });
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getValues()` will actually `unsubscribe` from the listener. `onSnapshot` returns a function that can be used to stop the listener which is `getValues` in this case. Try refactoring your code to:

```js
useState(() => {
  const q = query(collection(db, "users"));
  onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
    const updateUser = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      updateUser.push(doc.data());
    });
    setUsers([...updateUser]);
  });
}, [])
```